# Display Widget content in PWA Venia Theme

Tags: widget, pwa, venia, react, react-js

We are using [Venia PWA](https://github.com/magento/pwa-studio) 2.4.5 setup where frontend is displaying from ReactJs

I have added New Widgets in backend. How to display those content in Frontend of the website ?